# MySQL Tag System - How to select all the tags associated to the last N published posts?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by, sql-limit

I'm implementing a Tag System for my website, using PHP + MySQL.

In my database, I have the following three tables (so called "Toxi Solution"):

**Posts**

- Id
- DateTime
- ...

**Tags**

- Id
- Tag
- Slug

**TagsMap**

- Id
- Tag

where:

- Id = post's Id in Posts
- Tag = Tag's Id in Tags

Every post may have (in TagsMap) one or more tags associated to it.

Now I need to select all the tags associated to the last 20 published posts.

I've tried

```
SELECT T.Slug, T.Tag
FROM Posts A, TagsMap TM, Tags T
WHERE (SELECT Id from Posts WHERE DateTime <= NOW() ORDER BY Id DESC LIMIT 20)
AND T.Id = TM.Tag
AND A.Id = TM.Id
```

But I get

```
#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

And here's where I'm stuck (I'm not very experienced with MySQL).

Would you give me any suggestions?

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056 for SQL related questions.

Comment: Hi @AbsoluteBeginner Subquery after WHERE clause returns more than one row and if it return one row then you also get error. Because you don't use any assignment operator. Replace Post A table with this subquery and i think you'll get desired output.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @radocaw Do you really think that your comment - just a link, without any explanation - is useful?

Comment: Yes. Of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the table `Posts` first and then join to other 2 tables:

```
SELECT t.Slug, t.Tag
FROM Tags t
INNER JOIN TagsMap tm ON t.Id = tm.Tag 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT Id 
  FROM Posts 
  WHERE DateTime <= NOW()
  ORDER BY DateTime DESC LIMIT 20
) p ON p.Id = tm.Id
```

You may use `SELECT DISTINCT ...` if you are getting duplicate results.

Comment: Actually, there could be scheduled posts, so they have DateTime value `> NOW()`. I don't want to select them.

Comment: Maybe the first query line should be `SELECT t.Slug, t.Tag`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT T.Slug, T.Tag
FROM Tags T
    left join TagsMap TM on TM.Tag = T.id
    left join Posts A on A.Id = TM.id
WHERE A.Id in (SELECT Id from Posts WHERE DateTime <= NOW() ORDER BY Id DESC LIMIT 20)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sadly, I get this error: `#1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'`